# Silverlight slider control does not trigger mouseleftbuttondown event

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight

I have a slider like below:

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding TotalNumberOfPositions,Mode=TwoWay}" Value="{Binding CurrentPosition, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding StopSeekPosition, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding StartSeekPosition, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Slider>
```

The `MouseLeftButtonUp` event is working well and command will be triggered. However `MouseLeftButtonDown` is not triggered or it does not trigger my `StartSeekPostion` command. I have checked command names in MVVM. Everything is normal but it does not work. I really stuck on this. Is it something wrong with my code or is it an issue about slider control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is anything really wrong with your code nor is this an issue of the `Slider`, but when dealing with `RoutedEvents` you always have to keep in mind that anywhere along the route some eventHandling code can handle the event (and if further down the tree: before your handler had the chance), mark it as handled, and your handler will not be called.

So, most likely, the Slider control has a handler for `MouseLeftButtonDown` that sets `eventArgs.Handled = true;`

But you can prepare for this: use the method [UIElement.AddHandler( routedEvent, handler, handledEventsToo)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899(v=vs.95).aspx),
either call it in your code-behind and wire up the event and eventHandler there, or write your own trigger (like `<MouseLeftButtonDownEventTrigger HandledEventsToo="true">`) with a flag `HandledEventsToo`.

Code-Behind

```
mySlider.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
    new MouseButtonEventHandler( HandleMouseLeftButtonDown ), handledEventsToo: true);
...
private void HandleMouseLeftButtonDown( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e ){...}
```

custom trigger

```
public class MouseLeftButtonDownEventTrigger : TriggerBase<UIElement>
{
    public bool HandledEventsToo { get; set; }

    public bool MarkHandled { get; set; }

    private readonly MouseButtonEventHandler m_buttonDownHandler;

    public MouseLeftButtonDownEventTrigger()
    {
        m_buttonDownHandler = Invoke;
    }

    private void Invoke( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs eventArgs )
    {
        InvokeActions( null );
        if (MarkHandled) eventArgs.Handled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.AddHandler( UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
            m_buttonDownHandler, HandledEventsToo );
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.RemoveHandler( UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
            m_buttonDownHandler );
        base.OnDetaching();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have decided to use MouseLeftButtonDown event in code-behind. I have called the function in this event using `(LayoutRoot.DataContext as Model).Method();` and it worked.